# Run function after function from URL

Tags: javascript, function, url

I wrote a short script that clicks on specific buttons on a page. I run it from the URL bar. The script looks like this:

```
javascript:(function() { 
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('primaryButton');
    for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].click();
    }
})()
```

But whenever I try to add another function that the script will run after clicking on the buttons, it just doesn't happen. I try adding a simple command such as alert like this:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('primaryButton');
    for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].click();
    } 
    alert('test');
})()
```

But the second command (alert) isn't being executed. Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: check the browsers developer tools console for the error so you'll see what you're doing wrong, and why the javascript throws an error before finishing the for loop ... hint ... `<=` is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an uncaught error. Thank you for the suggestion  Jaromanda X.